# Finding the longest sentence by word from a text file

Tags: java, algorithm, search

I was able to find the longest word in the text file and now I'm working on finding the longest sentence by word. Is the algorithm similar to searching the longest word?
Here's my code to find the longest word:

```
    public static int getLongestWord() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String longestWord = "";
    String current;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("t1.txt"));

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        current = scan.next();
        if (current.length() > longestWord.length()) {
            longestWord = current;
        }

    }
    scan.close();
    return longestWord.length();
}
```

UPDATE!
Thanks for the help. I was able to get the longest word and now I'm counting the number of words within the longest sentence. Somehow, the counter is a bit off.
Here's what I have:

```
    public static String getLongestSentence() throws FileNotFoundException {
    int numWords = 0;
    String longestSentence = "";
    String currentSentence = "";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("t1.txt"));

    while (scan.hasNext()) {

        currentSentence = getNextSentence(scan);

        if (currentSentence.length() > longestSentence.length()) {
            longestSentence = currentSentence;
        }
    }
    scan.close();
    String[] wordList = longestSentence.split("\\s+");
    numWords += wordList.length;
    System.out.println(longestSentence);
    System.out.println("Number of words in this sentence: " + numWords);
    return longestSentence;
}

private static String getNextSentence(Scanner scan) {
    String sentence = "";
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        sentence += " " + scan.next();
        if (sentence.contains("."))
            break;
    }
    return sentence;
}
```

The longest sentence in my text file contains 30 words but my counter is off by 1, stating that it has 31 words. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: You should probably keep your file-opening code separate from your longest-word-finding code.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Is the algorithm similar?  Well, the concept of saving the current longest and replacing it with the new longest would be the same.  Obviously the code to detect which thing *is* the longest would be different.

Comment: Right. I was thinking of storing an entire sentence into an arrayList and the create a for loop that finds the longest sentence. Is this a good idea? How would I be able to count by words instead of characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are two things you have to consider :

**You consider that any sentence ends with a '.'**

then you may go for something like this

```
public static String getLongestSentence() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String longestSentence = "";
    String currentSentence = "";    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("t1.txt"));

    while (scan.hasNext()) {

        currentSentence = getNextSentence(scan);

        if (currentSentence.length() > longestSentence.length()) {
              longestSentence = currentSentence;
        }

    } 
    scan.close();
    return longestSentence;
}

private static String getNextSentence(Scanner scan) {
    String sentence = "";
    while(scan.hasNext()){
        sentence += scan.next();
        if(sentence.contains(".")) break;
    }
    return sentence;
}
```

**OR** if you want to consider more real-life cases, like elippsis, ASCII weird codes, other languages, well ... you will have to take a look at text analyzers like [Aylien](https://aylien.com/) because doing it from scratch will give you infinite headaches.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to get the longest sentence within the text file. However, when I print it on the console, it seems like all the whitespaces have been removed, meaning that all the words are together. Here's the output:
USforceshuntingelusivealQaedaandTalibanfightersineastern... so on.
How would you recommend to count the longest sentence by words instead of characters?

Comment: Oh yeah .. You may replace `sentence += scan.next();` with `sentence += " " + scan.next();`

Comment: Oh and you wanted to get the longest sentence **by word**, I did not see that. This code will indeed get the longest sentence by characters. What you may do instead of returning the sentence is returning the number of words (just increment a counter in the loop). Then compare all the counter values you had

Comment: I just updated my post. Would this approach work? Thanks!

Comment: The counter is off by 1 because the whole sentence starts with a space (because of the code I told you to change). Since this will always be the case, you can safely decrement the counter by 1, to make it right

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

### Part 1: Reading all file content into a variable

```
File file = new File("sentences.txt");
FileReader in = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
String line = br.readLine();
String fullContent = "";
while(line != null && line.length() > 0) {
    fullContent += line;
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

### Part 2: Declare two methods

#### This will split the entire file contents to different sentences, assuming sentence ending is '.'

```
private static String[] getSentences(String file) {             
     return file.split("\\.");          
}
```

#### This will find the word with the maximum length

```
public static int getMaxWordLength(String sentence, int maxWordLength) {
    for(String word : sentence.split(" ")) {
        String wordLength = word.trim().length();
        if(wordLength > maxWordLength) {
            maxWordLength = wordLength; 
        }
    }
    return maxWordLength;
}
```

### Part 3: Integrate two methods to find the sentence with largest word

```
int length = 0;
String largestSentence = null;
for(String sentence : getSentences(fullContent)) {
    int maxWordLength = 0;
    maxWordLength = getMaxWordLength(sentence, maxWordLength);
    if(maxWordLength > length) {
        largestSentence = sentence;
        length = maxWordLength;
    }
}
System.out.println(largestSentence);
```

Comment: I think thats the best approach and should be accepted answer.